# Localhost subdomain set up on ubuntu not working

Tags: ubuntu, subdomain

In my pc (running on Ubuntu) , I have configured apache and php.
I wanted to create a subdomain 'mysite.localhost' on my localhost

I have a folder  /var/www/mysite
Which I would like to access like http://mysite.localhost/

I followed the steps in http://thinkingnectar.com/2008/getting-ubuntu-to-work-creating-subdomain-in-localhost/

Basically did the following

Edited  /etc/host and added the following line

```
  127.0.0.1 mysite.localhost
```

Created a new configuration file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite 
using

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
    ServerName mysite.localhost

    <Directory /var/www/mysite>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Saved the file, and run the following:

```
sudo a2ensite mysite
```

Finally restarted the Apache Server.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

But on browsing http://mysite.localhost/ I get this message

"
Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname) .Your requested host "mysite.localhost" could not be resolved by DNS. "

Can anyone suggest what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue.
Apparently, there is nothing wrong with the sub-domain creation process.
I could not access the page because of some proxy settings.
I bypassed all proxy settings for localhost, 127.0.0.1  (to do this in Ubuntu: go to browser Edit>Preferences>Advance>Network >Settings tab and set *localhost, 127.0.0.1* for No proxy field  )
And now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of suggestions that might help, but these are just "shots in the dark" since I don't have access to a system right now that I can set up with a similar situation to yours for testing.

1. If you had your browser running prior to editing `/etc/hosts`, then restart your browser.  That should allow it to pick up changes to your `hosts` file.
2. In your question, you state that you want to serve your `mysite` files from `/var/www/mysite`, but in your Apache config file, you specify that the directory will be served from `DocumentRoot /home/username/mysite/`.  One of the two needs to change; either your expectation that the files will come from `/var/www/mysite`, or the `DocumentRoot` must be set to `/var/www/mysite` (and correspondingly, the `<Document ...>` declaration must then change as well.)

If neither of these work, then you should also try pinging the system to make sure it's responding correctly, as in the following:

```
$ ping mysite.localhost
ping: unknown host mysite.localhost

$ sudo vi /etc/hosts
(/etc/hosts now reads:
127.0.0.1   localhost mysite.localhost)

$ ping mysite.localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
```

Comment: you are right about correcting the document root directory path.I checked the path I have set and it is indeed pointing to the correct path (I made a typo while asking the question,i'm going to correct it).About pining the subdomain, that works too. but simply cannot browse the url mysite.localhost :-(

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be okay. Please double check  following entries in their respective files.

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.localhost

ServerName mysite.localhost
```

Comment: did check..Everything appears to be as it should .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added localhost and 127.0.0.1 entries in proxy server ,

Path: google chrome-->settings--> Show advanced settings--> Change proxy settings--> lan settings --> proxy server/advanced/ and add entries in the Exceptions box.